# How to get an B1/B2 visa to the US as an IT professional after US tightens H-1B visa rules?

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas

I want to get a US business visa and my interview at the embassy is around the corner. How should I prepare for it? On what conditions are they rejecting visas? It would be my first visa and I don't want to get dumped.

I have been sent there by my company for training purposes and the visa is also sponsored by the company

I want to know how should I prepare myself for the interview so that they don't reject my Visa request and what factors are causing visa rejection in recent days?

Comment: If you want to visit the US with a B-1 visa for a purpose that normally requires an H-1B visa then your application is likely to be refused, although there are some circumstances in which this is possible. What are the circumstances of your proposed visit to the US? This question is also probably better suited to [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're looking for.  B1/B2 visas are short-term visitor visas, totally different from the H-1B, which is a visa which allows employment.  Are you visiting short-term and not working, or aspiring to work in the U.S.?  If the latter, our sister site [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com) is a better place to ask the question.

Comment: You should revert the edit you mde to the title of your question. B1 is the correct visa type to attend training in the US. H-visas are for working in the US (which you won't be doing).

Answer (score 1):

May this is too trivial an answer, but anyway:

The criteria are here: See https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-visitors-business/b-1-temporary-business-visitor

Make sure you have thorough documentation for every "Eligibility Criteria" on the list.

Comment: OP has now edited the question to indicate that they are not trying to work in the US.